# ALERT SESSION VALUE FROM first page to 2nd page using JQuery,ajax, or javascript

Tags: session

hi guyz this is my first time here. ahmmm i'd  like to ask some question regarding session. ahmm
how i cant alert session value from first page to 2nd page using jquery,ajax, or javascript??
please help, im new on that language. ):

Answer (score 0):

You can pass value from one page to other using url query string.

one link to second page add data as parameter like http://your-url.com?data=user-session-value

in the second page call the below javascript function in onload or where you need value

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

you can alert the value like `alert(getParameterByName('data'));`

In this way your data will show in url. if you don't want to show it then use localstorage. But you need to be in same domain. I mean u can't pass data from one website to other.

In page one just set the data in local storage like `localStorage.setItem('data', 'user-session-value');`To alert the data in second page call `alert(localStorage.getItem('data'));`

Hope this can solve your issue... Happy coding...

Comment: thanks for your answer sir but sorry i cant code that yet. im a newbie i dunno where to start your given code sir ): or how to put it on html. im to dull

Comment: are you using javascript or jquery in your applicaiton??

Comment: i usde javascript sir, im capable of using query to but i only have little knowledge. im new of using those language.